# pyautogui.click() doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, pyautogui

Actually, I have written a code where I've to lunch the application such that I've to click the on-screen keyboard using this `pyautogui.click()`. But it is not working on on-screen keyboard. I'll be pleased to have your precious opinion. Thanks in advance.

```
import os
import pyautogui as pg
import time
x= 195  
y=505
secret="secretpassword"
command = "application"
os.system(command)
pg.click(x, y)
pg.typewrite(secret)
pg.typewrite(["enter"])
```

If the application is already lunched this is working but i want to lunch it with os.system(command)
and after that enter my password and access to the application.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Is it possible that the window hasn't opened when the `click` command is called? Have you tried adding a short sleep statement between opening the program and clicking the location?

Comment: @sedders123 the program open as i want but after this the mouse move and the lick is not working, but if i open the program before running the script all is runing as excepted but i  don't want it that way i want the script to open the program and run the follow instructions

Comment: Yes most likely there's a time delay meaning the `click()` happened prior to the application being opened so it never got focus.  Or the `x, y` is not correct.  Try adding a `time.sleep(2)` between the `os.system(command)` and `pg.click(x, y)`.

Comment: @Idlehands like i told in my post all is working when the application is lunched so the x,y are correct i'm sure, tried with the sleep the mouse is not moving and nothing is happening

Answer (score 1):

I changed

```
os.system(command)
```

with

```
subprocess.Popen(command)
```

Now it's working

subprocess.Popen() is strict super-set of os.system().

Answer (score 0):

`os.system()` will block and wait for the application to exit.
This means that your click, in fact, will not execute until the opened appication closes.
To verify this, you can open a (python) shell and run following code:

```
import os
import pyautogui
def test():
    os.system('<something simple opening a window>')
    pyautogui.typewrite("I'm in the shell again!")
test()
```

To run your script as you want, use [`os.popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen), or, even better, [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). These will run the command without blocking.

If you do this, keep in mind your application will have startup time, so you will want to wait some time after the call as noted in the comments under your question.